# PHP: Need to merge/sort a multidimensional array based on one key in the dimension

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I hope I will be able to explain what I'm trying to do - and really hope someone will be able to help!  Here is the array I am working with

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [city] => Middletown
            [state] => OH
            [freq] => 146.610
            [pl] => 77.0
            [call] => W8BLV
            [distance] => 0.0
            [notes] => ottel
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [city] => Middletown
            [state] => OH
            [freq] => 146.715
            [pl] => 
            [call] => N8COZ
            [distance] => 0.0
            [notes] => ct
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [city] => Middletown
            [state] => OH
            [freq] => 147.315
            [pl] => 77.0
            [call] => W8JEU
            [distance] => 0.0
            [notes] => ottel
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [city] => Middletown
            [state] => OH
            [freq] => 443.5370
            [pl] => 118.8
            [call] => W8MUM
            [distance] => 0.0
            [notes] => oe oe
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [city] => Middletown
            [state] => OH
            [freq] => 444.4750
            [pl] => 100.0
            [call] => AG8Y
            [distance] => 0.0
            [notes] => ottel
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [city] => Middletown
            [state] => OH
            [freq] => 444.8250
            [pl] => 77.0
            [call] => W8BLV
            [distance] => 0.0
            [notes] => oel
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [city] => Monroe
            [state] => OH
            [freq] => 443.0870
            [pl] => 
            [call] => KC8ECK
            [distance] => 4.3
            [notes] => oep
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [city] => Franklin
            [state] => OH
            [freq] => 145.290
            [pl] => 118.8
            [call] => WB8ZVL
            [distance] => 5.5
            [notes] => o(ca)r
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [city] => Franklin
            [state] => OH
            [freq] => 442.4250
            [pl] => 77.0
            [call] => WE8N
            [distance] => 5.5
            [notes] => Oae(ca)
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [city] => Franklin
            [state] => OH
            [freq] => 443.1500
            [pl] => 118.8
            [call] => WB8ZVL
            [distance] => 5.5
            [notes] => o(ca)r
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [city] => Springboro
            [state] => OH
            [freq] => 145.490
            [pl] => 77.0
            [call] => W8CYE
            [distance] => 8.9
            [notes] => oe
        )

)
```

The output I'm looking to get needs to be something like this:

```
$rpt[0] ="Middletown 146.61/77, 146.715, 147.315/77, 443.537/118.8, 444.475/100, 444.825/77";
$rpt[1] = "Monroe 443.087";
$rpt[2] = "Franklin 145.29/118.8, 442.425/77, 443.15/118.8";
$rpt[3] = "Springboro 145.49/77"
```

The fields I am most interested in are the city, freq, pl - And if you look at the first array, I have removed the trailing zeros on the output array. 
There are also a couple of times when I may need to use the call field, and the notes field, but if someone can point me in the right direction I probably will be able to figure
the rest I need - the call field and notes field would not be used often.
I have tried a couple of different foreach loops, but I am still pretty much a novice at PHP - and what I've done hasn't worked correctly, and I'm at the point were I need a little help.

Thanks in advance for the help,
LeRoy, KD8BXP

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need:

```
// Here $items is your input array.

/* First, sort input array by freq */

function compareByFreq($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['freq'] == $b['freq']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['freq'] < $b['freq']) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($items, 'compareByFreq');



/* Aggregate required data */

$result = array();
foreach($items as $item)
{
    if (isset($result[$item['city']])) {
        $result[$item['city']] .= ', '. $item['freq'];
    } else {
        $result[$item['city']] = $item['city'] . ' ' . $item['freq'];
    }
    if (! empty($item['pl'])) {
        $result[$item['city']] .= '/' . $item['pl'];
    }
}

$result = array_values($result); // get rid of assoc keys
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($input_array as $item) {
    $output_array[$item['city']][] = array(
            'freq' => $item['freq'],
            'pl' => $item['pl']
        );
}
```

With this, `$output_array` will end up as an associative array whose keys are cities, and whose values are lists of freq+pl arrays:

```
Array
(
    ["Middletown"] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [freq] => 146.610,
                    [pl] => 77.0
                ),
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [freq] => 146.715,
                    [pl] =>
                )
            // etc...
        )
    // etc...
)
```

(And you're welcome - Amber, `KC9HTI`)

## Edit

Once you've run the above code, you can use this code to get the final format you wanted:

```
foreach($output_array as $city => $freq_list) {
    $freqs = array();
    foreach($freq_list as $freq) {
        $freq_str = $freq['freq'];
        if($freq['pl']) $freq_str .= "/" . $freq['pl'];
        $freqs[] = $freq_str;
    }
    $rpt[] = $city . " " . implode(", ", $freqs);
}
```

`$rpt` should then have the array you want.

Comment: Amber, Thanks for the quick answer...Not quite what I was looking to do, but much much closer then I was getting on my own! I think I will be able to work this thou. Thank you very much for the help.
LeRoy, KD8BXP

Comment: Hm. Let me see if I can adjust this to more closely meet your needs. :)

Comment: See if the bit I added at the bottom is helpful.

Comment: Amber, Prefect! I see you are a fellow ham - this might interested you - I am working on a PHP script that will SMS you the Freqs for towns you are located near based on your APRS location...Still needs some tweaking, but the output of the last edit was what I was looking for! the code for the main project is at http://code.google.com/p/aprs2twitter - Thanks again for the help - LeRoy, KD8BXP